# Python - executing things in parallel?

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I have a project using two Raspberry Pis, where one should send the control signals to the other one, which should recieve and process them to control some Servomotors accordingly, all done in Python.

Now that is not a problem for me, but the problem lies in recieving the signals:
The method I use to ensure long ranges, needs to be in sync perfectly and has a timeout period. If it is not perfectly in sync, it waits for the signal and can stop the whole program for approx. 5 seconds or so.

Now, is there any possibility to let the checking and the moving be done at the same time, so that the movement stops when the signal says to stop but at the same time the checking does not interrupt the movement?

-Chrono

Comment: I'm no expert on the Raspberry Pi, but it sounds like the [threading](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html) or [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing) modules are what you're looking for.

Comment: You might want to check this: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_multithreading.htm

Comment: Thank you guys! I can finally finish my drone hopefully!